# <f:widget.paginate> show more items then given from controller

Tags: typo3, extbase

In my own extension I want to limit the shown items. From my flexform I get the set value = 5
**EventController.php**:

```
$showMaxItems = (int)$this->settings['event']['maxItems'];
```

and found the maxItems:

```
$events = $this->eventRepository->findLimited($showMaxItems);
```

and assign to the view:

```
$this->view->assign('events', $events);
```

**EventRepository.php**

```
public function findLimited($limit) {
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    return $query->setLimit($limit)
        ->execute();
}
```

**List.html shows maxItems**

```
<f:for each="{events}" as="event">
</f:for>
```

**List.html with widget.pagination always shows 10 items**

```
<f:widget.paginate objects="{events}" as="paginatedEvents">
    <f:for each="{paginatedEvents}" as="event">
    </f:for>
</f:widget.paginate>
```

When I show debug data in EventController in both versions I have 5 items

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($events);
```

Is this a bug from me or extbase? I found https://forge.typo3.org/issues/79559 but does not fit to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the Pagination Widget overrides the limit you set via setLimit().

If you want pagination on a Result set with custom Limit or Offset, you're going to have to convert your QueryResult into an array, and paginate that.

Comment: Could you provide an example how to paginate serverside? E.g. if the rep has 1000 records ... In the frontend I want 100 records and when 'paginate' on the second tab to load the next 100 records ... and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to limit the repository call, just get all objects independent from the pagination, like e.g. `$this->eventRepository->findAll()`

In the paginate View Helper you need the configuration argument and the View Helper does the limitation for you:

```
<f:widget.paginate objects="{events}" as="paginatedEvents" configuration="{itemsPerPage: '{settings.event.maxItems}'}">
  <f:for each="{paginatedEvents}">
    ...
  </f:for>
</f:widget.paginate>
```

See: https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/Widget/PaginateViewHelper.html

Comment: I want to limit maxItems in plugin flexform and not itemsPerPage. Example: maxItems=5; itemsPerPage=10; no pagination needed. Example2: maxItems=(not set=all); itemsPerPage=10; pagination needed